# Visual Studio 2013 Compiler Warnings

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I work in a corporate environment where updates are pushed to indiscriminately to developer machines. I'm working in Windows 7. Very recently I have begun receiving VS 2013 compiler dependencies warnings.

When I saw the warnings, I ran VS 2013 Update 5. But the warnings persist.

Should I worry about these warnings?

If I should worry, how can I resolve them?

Thanks

[image: Example of some warnings]

Answer (score 0):

I have abandoned this question. I realized that it would be better to migrate to VS 2015 rather than trying to shoehorn in the code needed into VS 2013.